# Unable to upload files > 1mb in Rancher; Nginx returns 413 error code for file sizes >1mb. How to modify configuration to allow for larger uploads?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, rancher, configmap

I am not unable to upload files that are larger than 1mb.  Nginx is responding with a 413 when the file size is greater than 1mb in Rancher.

I tried to locate the NGINX configuration in Rancher but I was unable to find it. I checked in the storage section in the Rancher namespace, where the configmaps were but I did not see a data section in that configmap where the nginx.conf would be

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rancher and you are experiencing an issue where you cannot upload files larger than 1MB, the solution is to increase the **client-max-body-size** annotation in the Rancher ingress controller.

To do this, follow these steps:

- Go to the **Ingress** tab in the Rancher UI.
- In the **Namespace** dropdown, select c**attle-system**.
- Click on the name of the ingress controller.
- In the Annotations section, click Add.
- In the Key field, enter **nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-max-body-size**.
- In the **Annotations** section, click **Add**.
- In the **Key field**, enter **nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-max-body-size**.
- In the Value field, enter a value **greater than 1MB**. For example, to
  set the limit to 10MB, enter 10M.
- Click Save.

Once you have completed these steps, you should be able to upload files larger than 1MB.

Additional Information:

- The **client-max-body-size** annotation sets the maximum size of the request body that the ingress controller will accept.
- The default value for **client-max-body-size** is 1MB.
- You can set **client-max-body-size** to **0** to **disable** the limit.

I hope this helps!